# How to add Row according to system date when there is no row for that date in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe whihc looks like

```
Date        Value1   Value2  Value3   Value4
2018-02-10  1        2       4        3
2018-02-09  2        4       1        2
2018-02-08  3        1       1        3
```

Considering today as 2018-02-13, how can i add two rows one for 2018-02-11 and 2018-02-12 in the above data frame with 0 value in all the fields.

Output DF:

```
Date        Value1   Value2  Value3   Value4
2018-02-12  0        0       0        0
2018-02-11  0        0       0        0
2018-02-10  1        2       4        3
2018-02-09  2        4       1        2
2018-02-08  3        1       1        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using the `complete` function from the [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) package. The `full_seq` function is handy to create complete list of dates. `dat2[is.na(dat2)] <- 0` is to replace all `NA` to 0.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
  complete(Date = full_seq(c(Date, ymd("2018-02-12")), period = 1)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

dat2[is.na(dat2)] <- 0

dat2
#         Date Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
# 1 2018-02-12      0      0      0      0
# 2 2018-02-11      0      0      0      0
# 3 2018-02-10      1      2      4      3
# 4 2018-02-09      2      4      1      2
# 5 2018-02-08      3      1      1      3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Date        Value1   Value2  Value3   Value4
'2018-02-10'  1        2       4        3
                  '2018-02-09'  2        4       1        2
                  '2018-02-08'  3        1       1        3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try with `complete` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
l1 <- setNames(as.list(rep(0, 4)), names(df1)[-1])
complete(df1, Date = seq(as.Date("2018-02-12"),  min(Date),
   by = "-1 day"), 
       fill = l1) %>%
   arrange(desc(Date))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  Date       Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
#  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2018-02-12   0      0      0      0   
#2 2018-02-11   0      0      0      0   
#3 2018-02-10   1.00   2.00   4.00   3.00
#4 2018-02-09   2.00   4.00   1.00   2.00
#5 2018-02-08   3.00   1.00   1.00   3.00
```

Comment: Those five rows was just for example i want to pass full dataframe containing ~500 Rows.

Comment: @Rahulshah  If you notice the code, I am taking the sequence of date of your interest with the miniimal date of the 'Date' (assuming it is of Date class).  So it should work whether it is 100 or 500 rows